# log-likelihood of normal distributed fitted using MLE

Tags: normal-distribution, maximum-likelihood, likelihood

Suppose we fit a normal using MLE which means we have parameters $$\mu = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n x_i$$ and $$\sigma^2 = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i - \mu)^2$$

Then we calculate the log-likelihood as

$$
-\frac{n}{2}\left\{ \ln(2\pi) + \ln(\sigma^2) \right\} - \frac{1}{2} \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i - \mu)^2}{\sigma^2}
$$

But if we have chosen $\mu , \sigma^2$ to be the MLE estimates then we can rewrite as 
$$
-\frac{n}{2}\left\{ \ln(2\pi) + \ln(\sigma^2) \right\} - \frac{1}{2} \frac{n\sigma^2}{\sigma^2}
$$
or
$$
-\frac{n}{2}\left\{ (1+ \ln(2\pi))  + \ln(\sigma^2) \right\} 
$$

Is this correct? I ask because I am looking at an example where an author does this. We are not supplied with the $x_i$ data. But we are told the volatility in an earlier example supposedly on same data is 20%. So that the sum in the brackets is

$$ (1+ \ln(2\pi))  + \ln(0.2^2) = -0.381 $$

so that the log-likelihood is $0.19n$.

The issue is that the author then quotes a negative log-likelihood for this example. Am I doing something incorrectly?